# H.264 image encoding using Media Foundation .NET

Tags: c#, performance, .net, video

We have some video analysis software written in c# .NET that uses OpenCV via the [Emgu.CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) wrappers. The video frames come from a GiGEVision camera (not a normal capture device) which are then analysed, graphically annotated, and then encoded to a video file.

Previously we have used the OpenCV [VideoWriter](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Video_Files) class to encode the video. However, the VideoWriter class uses video-for-windows codecs and often corrupts the indexing of the output file.

After much searching I am yet to find another .NET implementation of encoding frames to H264 video, so I decided to write my own. The code below is based on the [MediaFoundation C++ SinkWriter tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx) and implemented in .NET using the [MediaFoundation.NET](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiz2JH5rpXOAhULG5QKHfeoBCcQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmfnet.sourceforge.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNHR6T0EfF56DSDQC68_jFRO7MzHoA&sig2=pls3irDGm98XCUsfazslYA) wrapper.

The main changes I have made are:

- Everything is in a single thread, due to problems accessing the WriteFrame method from other threads. I believe this is due to interacting with the underlying COM object but I've no experience with that.
- New frames are passed to the thread using a `BlockingCollection`
- IDisposable was implemented to make sure Stop() is called.

Some questions:

- Is the thread implementation using `CancellationTokenSource` appropriate?
- Is `BlockingCollection` the best way to pass the frames in?
- Is it possible to reuse the IMFMediaBuffer and IMFSample objects? If so, should I do this? Will it improve efficiency?
- Is the implementation of IDisposable correct?

Code:

```
class MFVideoEncoder : IDisposable
{
    private int videoBitRate = 800000;
    const int VIDEO_FPS = 30;
    const int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 3;
    const long TICKS_PER_SECOND = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
    const long VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION = TICKS_PER_SECOND / VIDEO_FPS;

    public bool HasStarted = false;

    private IMFSinkWriter sinkWriter;
    private int streamIndex = 0;
    private int frameSizeBytes = 0;
    private long frames = 0;

    private int videoWidth = 0;
    private int videoHeight = 0;
    private string outputFile = "//output.mp4";

    private CancellationTokenSource encodeTaskCTS;
    private Thread encodeThread;

    BlockingCollection<Emgu.CV.Mat> FrameQueue = new BlockingCollection<Emgu.CV.Mat>();

    public MFVideoEncoder()
    {

    }

    public void Start(String outputFile, int width, int height, int bitRate)
    {
        this.videoWidth = width;
        this.videoHeight = height;
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
        this.videoBitRate = bitRate;

        frames = 0;
        frameSizeBytes = BYTES_PER_PIXEL * videoWidth * videoHeight;
        HasStarted = false;

        encodeTaskCTS?.Dispose();
        encodeTaskCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = encodeTaskCTS.Token;

        encodeThread = new Thread(() => EncodeTask(token));
        encodeThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        //encodeThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        encodeThread.Start();
    }

    public void Start(String outputFile, int width, int height, double compressionFactor)
    {
        int bitRate = (int) (VIDEO_FPS * width * height * BYTES_PER_PIXEL / compressionFactor);
        Console.WriteLine("# Bit rate: {0}", bitRate);
        Start(outputFile, width, height, bitRate);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (HasStarted)
        {
            encodeTaskCTS.Cancel();                
        }
    }

    public void AddFrame(Mat frame)
    {
        Mat flippedFrame = new Mat(frame.Size, frame.Depth, frame.NumberOfChannels);
        CvInvoke.Flip(frame, flippedFrame, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Vertical);
        FrameQueue.TryAdd(flippedFrame);
    }

    private void EncodeTask(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Mat frame;

        // Start up
        int hr = MFExtern.MFStartup(0x00020070, MFStartup.Full);
        if (Succeeded(hr))
        {
            hr = InitializeSinkWriter(outputFile, videoWidth, videoHeight);
        }
        HasStarted = Succeeded(hr);

        // Check encoder running
        if (!HasStarted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("! Encode thread didn't start");
            return;
        }

        //Write frames
        var exit = false;
        while (!exit)
        {
            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                if (FrameQueue.TryTake(out frame, 200))
                {
                    WriteFrame(frame);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("! Thread exit: " + ex.Message);
                exit = true;
            }
        }

        //Clean up
        sinkWriter.Finalize_();
        COMBase.SafeRelease(sinkWriter);
        MFExtern.MFShutdown();
    }

    private int InitializeSinkWriter(String outputFile, int videoWidth, int videoHeight)
    {            
        IMFMediaType mediaTypeIn = null;
        IMFMediaType mediaTypeOut = null;
        IMFAttributes attributes = null;

        int hr = 0;

        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFCreateAttributes(out attributes, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = attributes.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, 1);
        //if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = attributes.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = attributes.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_LOW_LATENCY, 1);

        // Create the sink writer 
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(outputFile, null, attributes, out sinkWriter);

        // Create the output type
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out mediaTypeOut);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Video);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.H264);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, videoBitRate);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, (int) MFVideoInterlaceMode.Progressive);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFSetAttributeSize(mediaTypeOut, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, videoWidth, videoHeight);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeOut, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeOut, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = sinkWriter.AddStream(mediaTypeOut, out streamIndex);

        // Create the input type 
        if (Succeeded(hr))  hr = MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out mediaTypeIn);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeIn.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Video);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeIn.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.RGB24);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = mediaTypeIn.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, (int)MFVideoInterlaceMode.Progressive);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFSetAttributeSize(mediaTypeIn, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, videoWidth, videoHeight);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeIn, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeIn, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = sinkWriter.SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, mediaTypeIn, null);

        // Start accepting data
        if (Succeeded(hr))  hr = sinkWriter.BeginWriting();

        COMBase.SafeRelease(mediaTypeIn);
        COMBase.SafeRelease(mediaTypeOut);

        return hr;            
    }

    private int WriteFrame(Mat frame)
    {
        if (!HasStarted) return -1;

        IMFSample sample = null;
        IMFMediaBuffer buffer = null;

        IntPtr data = new IntPtr();
        int bufferMaxLength;
        int bufferCurrentLength;

        int hr = MFExtern.MFCreateMemoryBuffer(frameSizeBytes, out buffer);

        if (Succeeded(hr))  hr = buffer.Lock(out data, out bufferMaxLength, out bufferCurrentLength);
        if (Succeeded(hr))
        {
            using (AutoPinner ap = new AutoPinner(frame.Data))
            {
                hr = MFExtern.MFCopyImage(data, videoWidth * BYTES_PER_PIXEL, frame.DataPointer, videoWidth * BYTES_PER_PIXEL, videoWidth * BYTES_PER_PIXEL, videoHeight);
            }
        }
        if (Succeeded(hr))  hr = buffer.Unlock();
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = buffer.SetCurrentLength(frameSizeBytes);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = MFExtern.MFCreateSample(out sample);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = sample.AddBuffer(buffer);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = sample.SetSampleTime(TICKS_PER_SECOND * frames / VIDEO_FPS);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = sample.SetSampleDuration(VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = sinkWriter.WriteSample(streamIndex, sample);
        if (Succeeded(hr))  frames++;

        COMBase.SafeRelease(sample);
        COMBase.SafeRelease(buffer);

        return hr;
    }

    private bool Succeeded(int hr)
    {
        return hr >= 0;
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (HasStarted)
                {
                    Stop();
                }
            }
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What all additional resources does this require to get working besides `MediaFoundation.NET`, `EmguCV`? For example, what is `AutoPinner`?

Comment: @geometrikal, did you ever implement the changes suggested?
If so, would you be willing, to post your updated code / link to a to a repository containing it?

Comment: @BradleyMoxon-Holt No, we ended up sticking with the opencv version. It was faster for the same bitrate, and we could control the speed by changing the compression in the codec settings, and this was easier for the users. The problem with corrupted files was due to not waiting for all the frames to be written before disposing the `VideoWriter`. With the answer below, IIRC the first point was important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I got this code working, so kudos for writing code that works. I don't have a lot of experience with Media Foundation or EmguCV, but I did want to share a few observations on your implementation.

- It appears to be a feature of this implementation that `Start` and `Stop` can be called more than once, possible to produce several output files over the lifecycle of a single `MFVideoEncoder` instance. However, this is weird and probably not completely implemented.

  - What happens when you call `Start` a second time? Your `encodeTaskCTS` is disposed, which is nice, but not cancelled first, and also you handed that cancellation token into another thread which is probably still alive, so there's a resource which will may be referenced after disposal.
  - Several properties, such as `HasStarted` and `frames`, are written in both `encodeThread` and the calling thread. They're not set up for cross thread access (eg, safe order of operations with locking), so this is almost certainly not going to work correctly *unless* `Start` is called *once and only once* over the `MFVideoEncoder` lifecycle.
  - `encodeThread` will be set to the reference to the newly created thread, so the previous thread will be GC'd at some unpredictable point in the future
  - `FrameQueue` doesn't get cleared, so your subsequent output files will probably contain frames from previous batches.
  - **Recommendation**: It doesn't appear to be particularly expensive to instantiate new `MFVideoEncoder`'s, so I'd say refactor it to enforce 1 output file per lifecycle. The simplest diff would be to make `Start` and `Stop` private, and call `Start` from your constructor. Then everything will be a lot safer.
- I think a `BlockingCollection` is perfectly fine to move frames onto the encoding thread.

  - You can actually take advantage of it more than you are already. For example, you could use `IsCompleted` in your `while` loop in `EncodeTask`, instead of doing `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. This would have the extra benefit of draining out the frame queue when `Stop` is called, instead of instantaneously halting frame processing as it does now.
  - It's possible to call `AddFrame` after `Stop`, currently. But if `Stop` calls `FrameQueue.CompleteAdding()`, then this will be prevented automatically.
  - `AddFrame` returns `void`, but `FrameQueue.TryAdd` reports whether adding the frame was successful or not. So your API consumers don't know if their frames will be processed or not. If whatever your scenario is legitimately allows for frames to not be added for processing, then it sounds important enough to report back to the caller.
  - **Recommendation**: Use more of `BlockingCollection`. Also, either change the signature of `AddFrame` to `bool` and return `FrameQueue.TryAdd`, or, use more of `BlockingCollection` & model add failures as exceptions thrown by `BlockingCollection`.
- In `EncodeTask`, what should happen if `MFStartup` doesn't succeed? Right now everything proceeds as if there were no error, except there's no output. That's kind of weird.

  - **Recommendation**: since `MFStartup` is critical to success, I'd throw an exception if it can't succeed.
- What happens if you call `Stop` instantly after `Start`? It's possible the thread won't start up & initialize `MFStartup` and set `HasStarted` in time, and then `Stop` won't cancel the CTS, which means that when it does get called, your frame write loop will wait forever. Probably not what you want.
- In `EncodeTask`, you're catching `Exception` in your loop. But the only exception you're expecting is `OperationCanceledException`, right?

  - **Recommendation**: Only catch the exceptions you're expecting, and let the rest bubble.
- You're pretty diligent about checking if return values succeeded for your Media Foundation calls, which is good. However, there's a couple cases where you're expecting `out` vars to exist even if the call wasn't successful. For example, in `WriteFrame`, what happens if `MFExtern.MFCreateSample(out sample);` fails? The adjacent calls will be skipped due to all the `if (Succeeded(hr))`'s, but what will `COMBase.SafeRelease(sample);` do if `sample` is unassigned?

  - **Recommendation**: ensure that either uses of `out` variables can survive working with unassigned vars, or, guard those uses more cautiously.
- All the `if (Succeeded(hr))`'s sure are awkward. I get not wanting to throw exceptions in hot code paths, but if everything is working normally, won't these calls all succeed?

  - **Recommendation**: investigate swapping `if (Succeeded(hr))`'s for something like `ThrowUnlessOK(hr)`, which you could wrap your MF calls with, to reduce the amount of conditions and noise associated with checking each return value. I can't say for sure that this would end up being *better*, but worth investigating.